# Create Objects from variable name

Tags: node-red, plc, siemens

I am using the S7-node to get data from SIEMENS PLC
I have a huge list of data to take out and I would to recreate an object
I tried to name the variable as :

```
line1.color.value
line1.speed.value
line2.color.value
line2.speed.value
```

if i try to get the values with msg.payload.line1.color.value is it not working, there is no object corresponding.

I would like to automatically create the objects line1,line2... following the name of the variable.
Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't really help us here, pleased edit the question to add a lot more detail. E.g. show the output of the S7 node

Comment: I mean the variable created is "line1.color.value" but it is not considered by nodered by a 3 level object (line 1, color, value) but as a single variable name that I cannot acces.
I changed the variable name to "line1-color-value" what i want is to automatically create the object line1 then append the color to line1 and then append the value to line1.color

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77661718/edit) the question to add the detail. (also don't assume we know anything about S7/PLCs). Including example output from the node will help.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. set function

To implement a 'set' function similar to the one in Lodash, you can use recursion to handle nested properties. Here's a simple JavaScript implementation:

```js
function set(obj, path, value) {
  if (typeof path === 'string') {
    path = path.split('.');
  }

  if (path.length === 1) {
    obj[path[0]] = value;
    return obj;
  }

  const currentKey = path.shift();
  obj[currentKey] = obj[currentKey] || {};

  return set(obj[currentKey], path, value);
}

// eg:
const obj = {};
set(obj, 'a.b.c', 42);
console.log(obj); // output: { a: { b: { c: 42 } } }
```

This 'set' function takes the object, the path, and the value to be set as parameters. If the path is a string, it is split into an array of paths. Recursively create nested properties and set the given value at the end of the path.

#### 2. use set function

```js
set(msg.payload,'line1.color.value',1);
set(msg.payload,'line2.color.value',2);
set(msg.payload,'line3.color.value',3);
```